# AOSP android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Tags: android, android-source

I build a apk in AOSP, then I pushed to phone, the error occurs.

> 01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smartcloud.test/com.smartcloud.test.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:195)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1315)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDrawableIfNeeded(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:234)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:755)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:88)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:128)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.smartcloud.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>   01-16 16:51:31.586 28823 28823 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more

**My Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

**Android.mk:**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, app/src/main/java)

#LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := \
    android-support-v7-appcompat \
    android-support-v4

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := TestHello

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false

LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/app/src/main/res \
    frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := \
    --auto-add-overlay

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use compatibility library in AOSP:

```
AppCompatActivtyi, v4.Fragment
```